# Xamarin Geolocator no me devuelve nada

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, geolocalización

Hola estoy usando `Xamarin` y `GeoLocator` para hacer una aplicación con Geolocalización, pero no me regresa los datos que le estoy pasando , y en el debug, me manda el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este error solo aparece cuando le doy click al botón que ejecuta el método que quiero. Previo a esto me tira ningún error.
La primera vez que lo ejecuté me activo el gps, pero cuando seguí usandolo ya ni eso ...

Este es mi código:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace OwService {
  [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
  public partial class PageGps: ContentPage {
    public PageGps() {
      InitializeComponent();
      btnGetLoc.Clicked += BtnGetLoc_Clickied;

    }

    private async void BtnGetLoc_Clickied(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      await RetriveLocation();
    }

    private async Task RetriveLocation() {
      var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
      locator.DesiredAccuracy = 10;

      var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10000), null, true);

      txtLat.Text = "Latitude: " + position.Latitude.ToString();
      txtLong.Text = "Longitude: " + position.Longitude.ToString();
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Yo no veo ningun error.Si te refieres a _has exited with code 0_,ese es el código de una finalización sin error.

Comment: Tuve una pregunta similar y ya resolví esta inconveniencia https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/137434/geolocalizaci%C3%B3n-xamarin-vs-android-problemas-con-la-altitud/137449#137449

Comment: Tienes puesto un retraso de 10 segundos, ¿has visto si completa esos 10 segundos? Pon un punto de parada en debug justo despues de var position a ver que ocurre.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primero, necesitas asegurarte de que has implementado el requerimiento de **PermissionsPlugin**.

1. En tu MainActivity, necesitas agregar el siguiente metodo.

   ```
   public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Permission[] grantResults)
   {
       PermissionsImplementation.Current.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
   }
   ```
2. Para que el Plugin de permissions funcione necesitas asegurarte que en tu metodo `OnCreate` fijes el CurrentActivity. Eso se traduce en agregar la siguiente linea antes de `LoadApplication(new App());`

   ```
   Plugin.CurrentActivity.CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity = this;
   ```

Finalmente, necesitas asegurarte de tomar en cuenta los permisos. Yo te recomendaria cambiar tu implemantacion de la siguiente manera.

```
        public async Task RetriveLocation()
        {
            try
            {
                var status = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Location);
                if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
                {
                    if (await CrossPermissions.Current.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationaleAsync(Permission.Location))
                    {
                        await DisplayAlert("Need location", "Gunna need that location", "OK");
                    }

                    var results = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(Permission.Location);
                    //Best practice to always check that the key exists
                    if (results.ContainsKey(Permission.Location))
                        status = results[Permission.Location];
                }

                if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
                {
                    var position = await CrossGeolocator.Current.GetPositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10000));
                    txtLat.Text = "Latitude: " + position.Latitude;
                    txtLong.Text = "Longitude: " + position.Longitude;
                }
                else if (status != PermissionStatus.Unknown)
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Location Denied", "Can not continue, try again.", "OK");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                txtLat.Text = "Error: " + ex;
                txtLong.Text = "Error: " + ex;
            }
        }
```

> Aqui hay un repositorio de prueba que funciona con el código anteriormente comentado. https://github.com/jesulink2514/DemoGPS

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Fuente: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GeolocatorPlugin

Comment: ¡Geeeente! él es el de http://www.somostechies.com :D ¡Bien ahí mi estimado! gusto de verte por estos lares :D