# Geolocalización Xamarin vs Android // Problemas con la altitud

Tags: c#, android-studio, xamarin, geolocalización

Hola amigos estoy desarrollando una aplicación que trabaja con Geolocalización, al principio la estaba desarrollando en **Android** pero me pidieron que me mudrara a **Xamarin** para poder desarrollar el proyecto de en multiplataforma. El problema surge que al testear su desepeño, me di cuenta que el programa que había desarrollado en **Xamarin** con **C#** tiene problemas para detectar las coordenadas de mi dispositivo cuando me encuantro en edificios de 2 o más pisos.
No sabía nada sobre si Xamarin tiene problemas para dectar dispositivos a diferentes altitudes. Caso contrario de **Android**. Que funciona bastante bien.

**Mi pregunta**  va por el siguiente lado, existe alguna forma de sensar la altitud de un dispositivo con el fin de mejorar el desempeño de mi App? es la altitud relevante para la geolocalización de un dispositivo? Existe alguna otra razón por la que este pasando esto?

Y por ultimo puedo confiar en **Miscrosoft** multiplataforma o mejor desarrollo mi proyecto en su lenguaje nativo para su mejor performance ?

Les dejo aquí mis métodos de ambos lenguajes por si gustan hacerme alguna observación.

```js
/*
Código en Android
*/

package com.example.sac_a.ows;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class GPS extends AppCompatActivity {


  private Button button;
  private TextView textView;
  private LocationManager locationManager;
  private LocationListener locationListener;


  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gps);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCheckGps);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gpsTxt);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    locationListener = new LocationListener() {
      @Override
      public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        textView.append("\n" + location.getLatitude() + " " + location.getLongitude());
      }

      @Override
      public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

      }

      @Override
      public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

      }

      @Override
      public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Intent myintent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(myintent);
      }
    };

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) !=
      PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
      ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) !=
      PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        requestPermissions(new String[] {
          Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.INTERNET
        }, 10);
      }
      return;
    } else {
      configureButton();
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 180000, 0, locationListener);


  }

  @Override
  public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
      case 10:
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
          configureButton();
        return;
    }
  }

  private void configureButton() {
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 180000, 0, locationListener);
      }
    });
  }


  public void backMain(View view) {

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(GPS.this,
      MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);
  }
}
```

Codigo en Xamarin C# (el que en verdad me interesa)

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Plugin.Geolocator;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace OwService {
  [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
  public partial class PageGps: ContentPage {
    public PageGps() {
      InitializeComponent();

    }

    private async void BtnGetLoc_Clickied(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      await RetriveLocation();
    }

    private async Task RetriveLocation() {
      var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
      locator.DesiredAccuracy = 10;

      var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10000), null, true);

      txtLat.Text = "Latitude: " + position.Latitude.ToString();
      txtLong.Text = "Longitude: " + position.Longitude.ToString();
    }

  }
}
```

Muchas gracias a todos amigos de stack, son mi vida los amo :3

Comment: La importancia de conocer la altura la decides tú, si es necesario saber con precisión en qué planta estás, por ejemplo. De momento, las señales de los satélites no atraviesan edificios, por lo tanto el teléfono trata de posicionarse con otros métodos de menor precisión.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En caso de a que a alguien le interese ...

```js
/*Pasar de ...*/


locator.DesiredAccuracy = 10;

/* aaaa .... */
locator.DesiredAccuracy = 100;
```

Comment: justo ya estaba por decirte eso xD!!!! Brother, considera que Xamarin y Microsoft se están comiendo el mercado de desarrollo móvil :D Por cierto, no te he visto por la sala de chat, éntrale :D https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol

Comment: Lo siento amigo solo hecho el code en trabajo, ergo no tengo mucho tiempo libre, pero pronto me verás por ahí :) @fredyfx

Comment: listo hermano, te esperamos :D